# How to get the default locale on early stage

Tags: php, concrete5, concrete5-8.x

On c5.7 the config variable `concrete.multilingual.default_locale` stored the default locale of an concrete5 installation.
On c5-8 we can not access this variable anymore. How can I get this value on new c5-8 installations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since concrete5 provides multiple sites on the same installation, every site needs a specific default language. Therefore the default locale config variable has no meaning anymore and the default locale is stored in the db table `sites`.

Access the default locale of all defined sites:

```
$defaultLocales = [];
$sl = new \Concrete\Core\Site\SiteList();
$sites = $sl->get();
foreach ($sites as $site) {
    $defaultLocales[$site->getSiteID()] = $site->getDefaultLocale();
}
```

The following will show, how to get this value for the first site found with backwards compatibility for c5.7.

```
$defaultLocale = Config::get('concrete.multilingual.default_locale');
if (!$defaultLocale) {
    if (class_exists('\Concrete\Core\Site\SiteList')) {
        $sl = new \Concrete\Core\Site\SiteList();
        $sites = $sl->get();
        foreach ($sites as $site) {
            $defaultLocale = $site->getDefaultLocale();
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Src: [concrete/src/Entity/Site/Site](https://github.com/concrete5/concrete5/blob/8.2.0RC2/concrete/src/Entity/Site/Site.php)